# How to put pool name in a Bitcoin Block?

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools

If someone access blockchain.info, see blocks and Pool name who finded. I want know how sign this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Mining pools self-identify blocks they've created by putting an identifier into the freely choosable input space of the Coinbase transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Signed blocks come with a Relayed by IP address field belonging to the solver of the puzzle. Blockchaininfo then on its own, assigns names of mining pools to the respective IP addresses.

Comment: this is wrong answer

Comment: would you like to elaborate?

Comment: Blocks are not signed and they certainly don't include IP addresses when relayed. Blockchain.info does track what IP address it was relayed a transaction from first, but I assume that in the case of blocks they simply go by the self-identification included by the authoring mining pools.